# Weird UI of term in Doom

Tags: osx, term, doom

My terminal in Doom looks like shown in picture but I can't seem to find a way to solve this.

I have term activated in my init.el

[image]

Comment: What's the _questinon_?

Comment: My question is what could be causing the problem? And what can I do to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Please describe the problem. And put the question about the cause in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time - questions need to stand on their own. Thx.